# Blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values

Tags: php, angular, laravel, typescript

when am I try connect backend api using JWT it shows this issue?
[image]

Laravel code

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

```
<?php

Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api',
], function ($router) {

    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
    Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');

});
```

```
        \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class,
```

```
        'CORS' => \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class,
```

angular code

```
  onSubmit()  {
      return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/login', this.form).subscribe(
        data => console.log(data),
        erro => console.log(erro)
      );
  }
```

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Middleware:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $origin = $request->header('origin');
    $origin = $origin ?? '*';

    // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => $origin,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD, PATCH',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Set-Cookie',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'=> 'true'
    ];

    if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
        // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
    }

    $response = $next($request);

    if($response instanceof JsonResponse){
        foreach($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: this is perfect but I made small mistake in code which is I missed  this `use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;`